# Rspec Rails - Mock to be current_user to test the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

i've started writing tests for my controllers. For once of them, i need to be logged in, in order to check whether the page is rendered etc.

Since i'm using Devise that has a current_user helper over a User model, how can i form my :

```
describe "when it GETS 'town'" do
  it "should render the template and be successful" do
    get :index
    response.should render_template(:index)
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

so that i don't get the undefined "authenticate!" method (devise specific) error ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a good writeup on this topic on the [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29). Basically you need to add the Devise test helpers, then call `sign_in` to get a valid current user when your spec expects one.